# Find potential function from *scaled* vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given a non-conservative vector field $F$ that is everywhere *proportional* to the gradient of an unknown scalar potential field $f$, i.e., $\nabla f= s\cdot F$ pointwise for some other unknown scalar field $s>0$, when/how can we recover $f$ and/or $s$?   OK to assume that $f,s$ (and therefore the components of $F$) are all at least $C^2$ smooth functions in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Motivating example: In $\mathbb{R}^3$, $F(x,y,x)=(u(x,y,z),v(x,y,z),w(x,y,z))$ is everywhere normal to any level set of $f(x,y,z)$; given $u,v,w$ solve for $f$.

Comment: You need to solve the system of equations $\partial_{i}f=sF_{i}$

Comment: If you know a little about differential forms, you're starting with a $1$-form $\omega = u\,dx+v\,dy+w\,dz$ and your goal is to find $s$ so that $d\omega = \omega\wedge d(\log s)$. The fact that you know $F$ can be scaled to be conservative tells you that $d\omega$ is $\omega\wedge\phi$ for *some* $1$-form $\phi$.